# Convert string to datetime pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a DataFrame that contains strings which should be converted to datetime in order to sort the DataFrame. The strings are received from Syslogs.

[image]

The strings look like as the ones on the picture and below:

```
date
Mar 16 03:40:24.411
Mar 16 03:40:25.415
Mar 16 03:40:28.532
Mar 16 03:40:30.539
Mar 14 03:20:30.337
Mar 14 03:20:31.340
Mar 14 03:20:37.415
```

I tried to convert it with pandas.to_datetime(), but I received the following error:

> OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-03-16 03:40:24

I may need the nanoseconds as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is necessary specify `format` of string with [this reference](https://strftime.org/).
There is no year, so output `year` is default:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%b %d %H:%M:%S.%f')
print (df)
                     date
0 1900-03-16 03:40:24.411
1 1900-03-16 03:40:25.415
2 1900-03-16 03:40:28.532
3 1900-03-16 03:40:30.539
4 1900-03-14 03:20:30.337
5 1900-03-14 03:20:31.340
6 1900-03-14 03:20:37.415
```

You can add some year to column and then parse it like:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime('2020 ' + df['date'], format='%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S.%f')
print (df)
                     date
0 2020-03-16 03:40:24.411
1 2020-03-16 03:40:25.415
2 2020-03-16 03:40:28.532
3 2020-03-16 03:40:30.539
4 2020-03-14 03:20:30.337
5 2020-03-14 03:20:31.340
6 2020-03-14 03:20:37.415
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is using `pandas.to_datetime` as mentioned above. If you are not familiar with date string formatting, you can getaway using date parser libraries. Example `dateutil` library:

```py
# python -m pip install —user dateutil
from dateutil import parser
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': ['Mar 16 03:40:24.411',' Mar 16 03:40:25.415','Mar 16 03:40:28.532']})

# parse it
df['dates'] = df['dates'].apply(parser.parse)
print(df)
```

dateutil parser will add current year to your dates.

## vectoring

```py
# using numpy.vectorize
import numpy as np
df['dates'] =  np.vectorize(parser.parse)(df['dates'])
```

## Note:

This is not optional for large datasets and should be used only when `pd.to_datetime` is not able to parse date.

Comment: `.apply` shouldn't be preferred here as it's definitely not vectorized and it won't cache results. Use `pd.to_datetime` as it can reuse cached results.

Comment: That is true. I won’t use it unless parser offers more than pd.to_date